# Using docker service names from outside the network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My app has 2 dependencies which I specify in my **docker-compose**, a postgres and kafka service:

```
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
```

I run my code and tests **outside** the docker network, and use these two containers as my dependencies.

As these both expose **ports**, I can configure my app to hit them via: localhost:5432, localhost:9092. This works.

The problem I have is when I want to test the app image itself, I add this as a service to the docker-compose file:

```
  app:
      image: myapp
      links:
        - postgres
        - kafka
```

The app is still configured to use localhost, so I allow the app container to access my network using **--net=host**

Whilst the app container can now access localhost:5432 and localhost:9092 (confirmed by curling from inside the container), the host names fail to resolve when the code runs and the dependencies are unreachable - possibly as a result of using localhost from inside the container and confusing the client libraries? I'm really not sure.

It feels like the use of localhost in the app configuration isn't the right approach here. Is it possible to refer to the service names 'postgres' and 'kafka' from **outside** the docker network?

Comment: a stupid possibility, have you tried to set the hostname of the container to make it as the hostname of your local machine ? or even add the `/etc/hosts` line related to your local machine host to `/etc/hosts` inside docker (this can be done using docker-compose through `extra_hosts`)?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to continue using `localhost:xxx` in your app?

The best approach for you is to change connection strings in your application when it is being launched from `docker-compose`. You just use `postgres:5432` and `kafka:9092` and everything will work, because inside docker-compose network all machines are visible to each other under their service names.

If for some great reasons you insist on using `localhost` as a connection target, you need to turn **all** services into `host` mode. But remember - in this case **ports are not exposed**, so you access services with their **original** port values.

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    network_mode: "host"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    network_mode: "host"
  app:
    image: myapp
    network_mode: "host"
```

And by the way, **forget about links**. [They are deprecated.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

Comment: This approach works great for testing my app image when it runs inside docker compose, but it doesn't allow me to develop my code from outside the network (meaning I can't actively debug it, and just use the postgres/kafka containers as dependencies).

For instance how would I run say integration tests with this approach? I wouldn't want to add them as another service into docker-compose, but how are they going to talk to postgres:5432 when they're not inside the network?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question if it is possible to refer to the service names from outside the docker network